# Rundeck winrm configuration

Tags: powershell, configuration, winrm, rundeck

I have been trying to use Rundeck to send powershell commands to windows boxes.
I am using "rundeck-winrm-plugin"

https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-winrm-plugin

It says to configure it in either project.properties or framework.properties file.
Here is how my /var/rundeck/projects/SecureCloud/etc/project.properties file looks like.

```
project.name=Cloud
project.ssh-authentication=privateKey
project.ssh.user=Domain\\rundeck-user
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=jsch-ssh
project.ssh-keypath=/var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/id_rsa
resources.source.1.config.url=http\://localhost\:4567/puppetdb
resources.source.1.config.timeout=30
service.FileCopier.default.provider=jsch-scp
resources.source.1.type=url
resources.source.1.config.cache=true
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=overthere-winrm
winrm-user=Domain\\rundeck-user
winrm-password-storage-path=keys/ldap-rundeck-user-pass
```

I can't figure out how to define username and password according to this document:
https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-winrm-plugin

I already have winrm-user already defined so I don't know if I still have to define rundeck-user@Domain if yes, then how (I am using kerberos) ?
project.username=rundeck-user@Domain   ?

How to define hostname here ?
project.hostname=machine-name    ?

Should I even use /var/rundeck/projects/SecureCloud/etc/project.properties file when I already declared there:
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=jsch-ssh
and this doc says to put this line there:
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=overthere-winrm

If no, then where should I put my configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Username and password
   There are two ways you can define authentication

   - Basic:
     You can use a Secure option in the rundeck job and an option name that matches your node definition name for that option. You can set the username in the node definition as well
   - Kerberos:
     This is how you define the username (Make sure you use Caps for the domain as defined in the krb5.conf file)
     username="user@YOUR_DOMAIN.COM"
2. Hostname is defined in the node definition. To define a node you can do it under `/var/rundeck/projects/SecureCloud/etc/resources.xml` For example:

   node name="YOURSERVER" connectionType="WINRM_NATIVE" node-executor="overthere-winrm" winrm-password-option="winrmPassword" winrm-protocol="https" winrm-auth-type="basic"  username="YOURUSER" winrmPassword="winrmPassword" hostname="YOURHOSTNAME:PORT"
3. You don't need to define the node executor in your node definition if `overthere-winrm` is already set as the default node executor in the Configuration/Plugins/NodeExecutor section of the project in the Rundeck GUI

Answer (score 0):

you can follow [Rundeck Windows Nodes Configuration](http://www.techpaste.com/2015/08/rundeck-windows-nodes-configuration/) for the steps to follow for overthere winrm configurations.